# jQuery get all divs have children with class

Tags: jquery

I have some div's with id: row_(x).
I want to hide all div's (row_*) whose child divs contains, first 'customerType2' in class and second does not contains 'active'.

```
<div class="test" id="row_10" style="left: 100px; top: 100px; display: block;">
    <div class="customer customerType2" id="customer_10"></div>
    <div class="customerState active" id="customerState_10"></div>
    <a href="#" id="link_10" class="link">Nick</a>
</div>


<div class="test" id="row_11" style="left: 110px; top: 110px; display: block;">
    <div class="customer customerType2" id="customer_11"></div>
    <div class="customerState" id="customerState_11"></div>
    <a href="#" id="link_10" class="link">George</a> (This, must be hide when click button)
</div>
<br><br>
<button>Click me</button>
```

I tried something like this but it is not working:

```
$("button").click ( function() {
   $("div[id*='row_']").has("div[id*='customer_'].customerType2").not("div[id*='customerState_'].active").css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you used `.not()` is wrong,

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $("div[id*='row_']").has("div[id*='customer_'].customerType2")
      .not(":has(div[id*='customerState_'].active)").css('display', 'none');
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4xbr88qv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method like following.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("div[id*='row_']").filter(function() {
        var divs = $(this).children('div');
        return divs.eq(0).hasClass('customerType2') && !divs.eq(1).hasClass('active');
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="row_10" style="left: 100px; top: 100px; display: block;">
    <div class="customer customerType2" id="customer_10"></div>
    <div class="customerState active" id="customerState_10"></div>
    <a href="#" id="link_10" class="link">Nick</a>
</div>
<div class="test" id="row_11" style="left: 110px; top: 110px; display: block;">
    <div class="customer customerType2" id="customer_11"></div>
    <div class="customerState" id="customerState_11"></div>
    <a href="#" id="link_10" class="link">George</a> (This, must be hide when click button)
</div>
<br><br>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: this is correct too..  but i will get the first answer.. is shorter

Thank you again both guys!

Comment: First answer will also hide the `div` if you rearrange the children. @NickD